# InputTextArea Keyup event and focus

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to make a dynamic InputTextArea, using ajax. I explain: I have a inputTextArea where the user can write his text, but I want to limit the number of characters in this one.
As i don't want to make it server-side, basically by checking the size of this input at the submit step .
I try to make it dynamic: When the amount of characters is reached, the user input will be cut.

So, i write this code:

```
<h:inputTextarea value="#{bean.val}" id="area">
      <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{bean.cutoff}" execute="@this" render="area" />
</h ...>
```

And in my bean, the listener do very basic stuff:

```
public void cutoff() {
    if(val.length() > 100)
            val = val.substring(0, 100);
}
```

When i run it, i have the following problem: Everytime i type a letter, it losts the focus on the inputTextArea. So it's really boring.

I tried to add, in my a4j:ajax an attribute:

```
<a4j:ajax ... onbeforedomupdate="area.focus();"/>
```

But it doesn't works: I can type some letter, but the function (cutoff()) is no longer call.

So i don't know what to do. The first solution launch the function but lost the focus, the second get back the focus but doesn't launch the function (only when i do it the first time)...

If you have a solution to this problem, it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before dom update is not a good idea because the textarea is still not replaced. Try with oncomplete

Comment: I tried, unfortunately it does the **same thing** :(

Comment: Btw why don't you just implement that using javascript?

Comment: I think it's better to separate the process and the view. So I prefer to let my backing bean do the process and the jsf the view. :)

Comment: There are plenty solutions of this using Javascript. It would be even better to set a validator for this field for the server side when submitting it to the server. Note that **this is not a good use of ajax**.

Comment: Yep. Currently i use rich:validator which check the length when the input lost the focus. But still doesn't find a solution to the initial question. BTW, why a validator is **not a good use** of ajax ?